# Outlook 365: how to "convert" client-side rules into server-side rules

Tags: microsoft-outlook-365

I have an email account on an Exchange server that I am accessing by using Outlook 365 on an iPhone, an iPad and on a Windows 8.1 PC. In the past, I set up client-side rules on the PC that only fire when I open Outlook 365 on the PC. I would like to “translate” these into server-side rules. The rules have always been simple: when message A arrives from person X, move it to Folder B. I set up the client-side rules using one of the two conditions “when xyz is in the sender’s address” or “when xyz is in the message header”. These conditions are by default client-side rules. How can I translate these into server side rules with ease? For example, if I were to receive emails from 100 different people at Microsoft.com, I would like to just use wildcard@microsoft.com in the rule (where wildcard stands for everything that comes from Microsoft.com) and not 100 different email addresses.